# python regex to display text in parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I did a coding to get to print ext inside (" and within ") but i get the errors.

I mean ,if i have text: `hello everyone("Can you see")`, then it has to print as `Can you see`

My coding:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "<_io.TextIOWrapper ('C:/Python34/abcd.txt') mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>"
>>> m = re.search(r"(?<=\('\=\')[^\']*", s)
>>> m.group()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    m.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Your description says you need to find `("`, but your code has `('` instead. Should you be looking for one or the other, or both?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense yes my description was unmentioned and i need to display for both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your lookbehind a little:

```
(?<=\(')[^']*
```

and you'll have the following result:

```
>>> m = re.search( r"(?<=\(')[^']*", s)
>>> m.group()
'C:/Python34/abcd.txt'
```

To be able to match both `'` and `"` as you mention in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225317/python-regex-to-display-text-in-paranthesis/25225348#comment39291650_25225348), you'd need to create another capture group (for back referencing):

```
(?<=\((['"]))(.*?)\1
```

and thus:

```
>>> m = re.search( r"(?<=\(([\"']))(.*?)\1", s)
>>> m.group()
"C:/Python34/abcd.txt'"
>>> m.group(1)
"'"
>>> m.group(2)
'C:/Python34/abcd.txt'
```

Comment: how can i use it for both ("  ") and (' ')  ?,and i only need to print the text without codes!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, which will use either single or double quotes. The `group(1)` gives the inner string. This regex escapes the outer parens so they don't represent a grouping.

```
>>> m = re.search(r"\(['\"](.+)?['\"]\)", s)
>>> m.group(0)
"('C:/Python34/abcd.txt')"
>>> m.group(1)
'C:/Python34/abcd.txt'
>>> m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple regex: `('.*?')`. It does a non-greedy search for everything enclosed in quotes.

```
import re
s = "<_io.TextIOWrapper ('C:/Python34/abcd.txt') mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>"
regex = re.compile(r"('.*?')")
m = regex.search(s)
m.group()
```

It produces this output:

```
"'C:/Python34/abcd.txt'"
```

You can also go with `re.VERBOSE` regexes and `groupdict`:

```
import re
s = "<_io.TextIOWrapper ('C:/Python34/abcd.txt') mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>"
regex = re.compile(r"""
    \(
    (?P<quoted>'.*?')
    \)
""", re.VERBOSE)
m = regex.search(s)
m.groupdict()["quoted"]
```

Answer (score 1):

this regexp will do it:

```
m = re.search(r"(?<=\()[^\)]*", s)
```